# powershell change category color, error message?

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

So i got this script, it should change the category color in office365, from powershell.................................................................

Script:

```
$messages = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\messageid.csv

Connect-EXRMailbox -Mailbox "email@domain.com"
ForEach ($message in $messages){
$MessageId = $message.MessageId
$MailboxName = $message.MailboxName
    $Item = Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $MessageId 
     Set-EXRItemCategory MailboxName $MailboxName -Item $Item -Categories @("Green")

}
```

Error code:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
At line:17 char:19
+ ... stDomain = (New-Object system.net.Mail.MailAddress($MailboxName)).Hos ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:18 char:8
+             if ($Script:TokenCache.ContainsKey($HostDomain))
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
At line:17 char:19
+ ... stDomain = (New-Object system.net.Mail.MailAddress($MailboxName)).Hos ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:18 char:8
+             if ($Script:TokenCache.ContainsKey($HostDomain))
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Get-EXRAccessToken : No Access Token for MailboxName
At line:31 char:32
+ ...           $AccessToken = Get-EXRAccessToken -MailboxName $MailboxName
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-EXRAccessToken

Get-EndPoint : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AccessToken' because it is null.
At line:38 char:47
+         $EndPoint = Get-EndPoint -AccessToken $AccessToken -Segment " ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-EndPoint], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Get-EndPoint

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
At line:17 char:19
+ ... stDomain = (New-Object system.net.Mail.MailAddress($MailboxName)).Hos ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:18 char:8
+             if ($Script:TokenCache.ContainsKey($HostDomain))
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
At line:17 char:19
+ ... stDomain = (New-Object system.net.Mail.MailAddress($MailboxName)).Hos ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:18 char:8
+             if ($Script:TokenCache.ContainsKey($HostDomain))
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Get-EXRAccessToken : No Access Token for MailboxName
At line:24 char:20
+ ...           $AccessToken = Get-EXRAccessToken -MailboxName $MailboxName
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-EXRAccessToken

Invoke-RestPatch : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AccessToken' because it is null.
At line:32 char:92
+ ... $RequestURL -HttpClient $HttpClient -AccessToken $AccessToken -Mailbo ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-RestPatch], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Invoke-RestPatch
```

My Csv file:

```
"MessageId","MailboxName"
"<HE1P192MB018554247E4F4A81D830F19DD1820@HE1P192MB0185.EURP192.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>","email@domaion.com"
```

So my question is. Is it my code there is an error in, or is it in the Exch-Rest tool ?

Hope anyone knows how to fix this .

Have a really nice day!

Comment: `$MessageName` and `$MessageId` are never defined, so at this point I would say your code. If it's an incomplete sample, please update it

Comment: This is the [2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098100/change-category-color-in-powershell-via-csv-file#comment87216671_50098100) with this topic and nearly identical code. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a8bf4a3-d356-4852-b93c-3a72adb33b49/office365-set-category-color-code?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) seems to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it my code there is an error in, or is it in the Exch-Rest tool ?"
It's you. It's almost always you. That's half of why bugs in external libraries are so hard to find :)

Where do you initialise your $Mailbox variable? 
If it's from your CSV file, then you should use

```
$message.MailboxName
$message.MessageID
```

Comment: Hi. so i have added thouse 2. and got a CSV file with a messageID and email. But still getting same error as before.

Comment: @newbie You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50112988/edit) your answer to contain additional information not scatter this in comments